# Laravel send data via request to another project

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel api controller where I'm getting data from a table.

```
public function moveData() {
    $movelivesales = DB::table('st_sales_live')->get();
    return $movelivesales;
}
```

I'm getting all the data, now how can I send this data to another project api(this api is ready)  using request ? Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a route like this to get your data(`$movelivesales`):

```
Route::get('/your/path', 'YourController@moveData');
```

Then if you access:
http://yourdomain.com/your/path you will get a json of your data

You can get the data from api with php: `file_get_contents('http://yourdomain.com/your/path');`